# Onpress of touchableopacity is not working with "absolute"

Tags: react-native, position, absolute, touchableopacity, onpress

In my react native app i have view with centered text and edit icon i need to enable click functionality in this view. for that i used `TouchableOpacity`'s `onPress`. and in my style i need absolute position . then my `onPress` is not working.

I have code like this:

```
     <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.topBand}
        onPress={this._editPatientInfo}
      >
        <View style={styles.topView}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text style={styles.topTitle}>{topTitle}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end" }}></View>
          <Icon
            pencil
            name="pencil"
            type="font-awesome"
            size={20}
            onPress={ this._editPatientInfo}
          />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

styles:

```
topBand: {
    width: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: Colors.topBandColor
}
topView: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center"
}
```

When clicking the function is not getting triggered. If i remove `position: "absolute"`, from the style(`topBand`) it will work but without that the position is not correct.

What is the problem? How should i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your touchableOpacity with a view that has position absolute
then it may work

```js
<View style={styles.wrapper}>

 <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.topBand}
        onPress={this._editPatientInfo}
      >
        <View style={styles.topView}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text style={styles.topTitle}>{topTitle}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end" }}></View>
          <Icon
            pencil
            name="pencil"
            type="font-awesome"
            size={20}
            onPress={ this._editPatientInfo}
          />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

```js
wrapper:{
    width: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
},
topBand: {
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: Colors.topBandColor
}
topView: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But unfortunately  it is not  working ...

Answer (score 0):

Import TouchableOpacity from react-native-gesture-handler

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```